# Direct3D fails to render when on Laptop with nvidia optimus

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I'm developing a Direct3D control which needs to run on a Dell XPS with a NVIDIA Optimus. I'm using SharpDX and C#.  When I write code for the app on a workstation with only an NVIDIA graphics card it runs correctly. When I move it to the laptop, I select the NVIDIA graphics adaptor via code, however it does not render to the window. How can I get this to work correctly? Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I'm wondering, is it possible that even though the system reports it is using the integrated Intel graphics card that it is passing through to use the NVIDIA?

Comment: If the system says it uses the integrated graphics card, then it uses the integrated graphics card. Try setting it manually.

Comment: On this model, there is not a bios or configuration setting. I used the NVIDIA adapter when creating the device... however, it does not render to the window... If I create the device with the Intel adapter it works fine the performance is just not the best. Seems odd you'd have a high end card that can't be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way Optimus works.

It's not a case of either/or; instead with Optimus you get to choose between using only the Intel, or using the Intel AND the NV. In the latter case, the NV handles most of the work, then transfers the framebuffer to the Intel for the final Present to the screen.

In other words, the NV is not capable of presenting to the screen on it's own. If you select it in code when creating a device you will get a device that is not capable of presenting to the screen. Your code is only doing what you asked it to do but you probably didn't realise or expect this.

The correct way to enable "high performance" mode with Optimus is to export the NvOptimusEnablement global.

Sample code for this and further explanation of the technology can be found in the Optimus White Paper: http://www.nvidia.com/object/LO_optimus_whitepapers.html